# Twilio bulk sms without notification

Tags: twilio, sms, bulk

Twilio told that "We intend to end of life (deprecate) the Notify product on October 23, 2023."
https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/9198083260571-Transitioning-off-Notify

Twilio Notify alternative solutions
Twilio's SMS API is a great replacement for any Notify based SMS use cases. You can also use the message scheduling feature to schedule up to 500,000 messages!

This is my code with scuedule:

```
$sendAt = (new DateTime())->add(new DateInterval('PT61M'));
$msg= "Hi, Bonanza sale !";
foreach ($sendto_leads as $lead) // $sendto_leads means all phone number
{
$to=trim($lead['phone']);
$message = $client->messages->create(
$to,`your text`
[
"messagingServiceSid" => "###########################",
"body" => $msg,
"sendAt" => $sendAt->format('c'),
"scheduleType" => "fixed",
]
);      
}
```

This code is running smoothly with $sendto_leads 10, or 50 or 100, but when I tried with 10000 phone numbers then site is slow down. browser spining.
Please any one post solutions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's a limit in Twilio messeging API where you need to sepecify only one phone on each new message you send see:
https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181548-Can-I-set-up-one-API-call-to-send-messages-to-a-list-of-people.
there are alternatives where you can send the same message to multiple receipent at the same submission like bulksms sendbatch:
https://www.bulksms.com/developer/eapi/submission/send_batch/
I hope my answer has helped you find what you are looking for.

Comment: I want in Twilio without notification.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the website is slow because you're making 10000 HTTP requests in a serial loop. Instead of making all the HTTP requests and then responding to your own HTTP request, I'd recommend starting an asynchronous/background job and respond immediately to your own HTTP request, not waiting for the bulk SMS job to finish. Additionally, you could send multiple HTTP requests in parallel.

If the messages themselves aren't delivered fast enough, I'd recommend looking through [this document](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002943027-Understanding-Twilio-Rate-Limits-and-Message-Queues) and most likely you need to add more senders to your Messaging Service's Sender Pool